# How to reduce the speed of rotation in view ticker module

Tags: views

I created a view with `views ticker` for the newsfeed items. The newsfeed items are configured to vertical scroll with `speed: very slow.` But the rotation speed of the items are a bit fast and I'm inclined to reduce the speed of the rotation.

So, I looked into module files and tried to change the vTicker_speed values in the `views_ticker_style_plugin.inc` file located in the `../sites/all/modules/views_ticker/includes/`

[image]

I changed the values in the line 142. Previously, it was 1000 - one second to 40000 - forty seconds. But I couldn't get it reflected in the site. It scrolls with same speed as it was before.

Can any one suggest me how to reduce the speed. Or is there any other module to work with vertical scroll??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FADE effect, look in the folder xxxx of the module the views.ticker.fade.js file, and rise the value of the:

```
b = b || 4000;
```

to something like 10000 or 12000.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

It is not enough if you edit only options under `$form['vTicker_Options']['vTicker_speed'] = array(` but you also need to edit it's options under `$form['vTicker_Options']['vTicker_pause'] = array(` on line # 121 and related options are on line # 126, to get changes eye catching. Also you can change it's scrolling speed in drupal's edit view page under `Format -> settings -> SHOWVERTICAL SCROLLER OPTIONS -> Scroller pause`

After you did clear drupal cache or click on some link in the view's edit page and don't do anything and click on apply button, so that save button will be available on the top of the view's edit page, then click on save button to take effect with your manual edits.

also you can give your own option to `$form['vTicker_Options']['vTicker_speed'] = array(` if you interest. :)
Hope this will help.